# Color palette for overlapping binary images in R

Tags: r, image, plot, colors, venn-diagram

I have a set of N binary (1-0) images and want to make an image in R which shows how they overlap with one another.

As an example, suppose I had two of these binary images and each binary image displayed a circle, slightly off centre; one to the right and one to the left. In this case, I would want my display to look something like a Venn diagram.

My problem is this; at present, I have 5 of these images and I want them to look something like a Venn diagram with 5 'circles' (this is in quotes as they may be slightly different shapes). There are potentially 5!=120 possible ways that 5 'circles' can intersect one another and I have no idea how to define a colour palette in R that shows each of these possible intersections clearly.

Ideally, I want to produce something like the output of the `venn` R package (e.g. see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/VennDiagram/man/draw.quintuple.venn.html)), but where I have defined each of the sets myself using 5 different images. Does anyone know how I can do this?

---

Update: As requested I have provided 5 of my binary images in csv format here:

- [Image 1](http://www.filedropper.com/mask1)
- [Image 2](http://www.filedropper.com/mask2)
- [Image 3](http://www.filedropper.com/mask3_2)
- [Image 4](http://www.filedropper.com/mask4)
- [Image 5](http://www.filedropper.com/mask5)

In terms of code though, I must admit I haven't much idea where to start. I tried adding all the images together defining custom colour schemes using something like this:

```
# Read in files
mask1 <- read.csv(file = 'mask1.csv',sep=',', header=FALSE)
mask2 <- read.csv(file = 'mask2.csv',sep=',', header=FALSE)
mask3 <- read.csv(file = 'mask3.csv',sep=',', header=FALSE)
mask4 <- read.csv(file = 'mask4.csv',sep=',', header=FALSE)
mask5 <- read.csv(file = 'mask5.csv',sep=',', header=FALSE)

# Define some colors
mycols = c(lightgrey = 0, blue = 1, red = 2, orange = 3, green = 4, yellow = 5,
           purple = 6, sienna1 = 7, turquoise = 8, seagreen = 9, coral = 10,
           moccasin = 11, salmon = 12, rosybrown = 13, goldenrod = 14, khaki = 15,
           brown = 16)

# Sum them
example_mat = mask1 + mask2 + mask3 + mask4 + mask5

# Transpose
rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))
m1 = rotate(example_mat)

# Convert to long format
d = data.frame(Values = as.vector(m1),
               fillcol = names(mycols[match(m1, mycols)]),
               X = as.vector(row(m1)),
               Y = as.vector(col(m1)))

# Make a plot
graphics.off()
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_tile(color = NA, fill = d$fillcol) +
  theme_light() +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),                          
               
  axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                         axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
                          panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
```

But this fails because it does not distinguish each set, it also doesn't have enough colors and the overlap colors don't really resemble the colors of the sets which are overlapping. I.e. it is very far from the example given in [the venn package article I referenced already above.](https://rdrr.io/cran/VennDiagram/man/draw.quintuple.venn.html)

Comment: Please provide sample data and code attempted.

Comment: Of course, I will add sample data now. In terms of code though I must admit I am a little unsure where to even begin - I will include what I can.

Comment: The question has now been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably handle this a little differently, by plotting each image with its own color, but making it partially transparent so that you get the color overlaps for free without calculating them ahead of time.

We start by reading in the files:

```r
mask1 <- read.csv(file = 'mask1.csv', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
mask2 <- read.csv(file = 'mask2.csv', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
mask3 <- read.csv(file = 'mask3.csv', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
mask4 <- read.csv(file = 'mask4.csv', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
mask5 <- read.csv(file = 'mask5.csv', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
```

Then define a little helper function which will rotate each image dataframe and turn it into long format:

```r
mask_to_df <- function(mask, alpha, fillcol)
{ 
  mask <- t(apply(mask * alpha, 2, rev))
  data.frame(values = as.vector(mask),
             fillcol = fillcol,
             X = as.vector(row(mask)),
             Y = as.vector(col(mask)))
}
```

Then we can use `geom_raster` to plot, like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mask_to_df(mask1, 0.5, "red"), 
       aes(x = X, y = Y, alpha = values, fill = fillcol)) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_raster(data = mask_to_df(mask2, 0.5, "blue")) +
  geom_raster(data = mask_to_df(mask3, 0.5, "green")) +
  geom_raster(data = mask_to_df(mask4, 0.5, "yellow")) +
  geom_raster(data = mask_to_df(mask5, 0.5, "magenta")) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  theme_light() +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

And of course you are free to change the alpha and base color of each circle as you see fit.

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what I was looking for thank you!